# In-app Billing Check skuid

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I use this code for in-app billing in my project, this code works well but I can not check which item is purchased.

This is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    private BillingClient mBillingClient;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_three_buy_health)
    Button btn_three_buy_health;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_ten_buy_health)
    Button btn_ten_buy_health;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_twenty_buy_health)
    Button btn_twenty_buy_health;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_fifty_buy_health)
    Button btn_fifty_buy_health;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    enableOrDisableButtons(true);
                } else {
                    enableOrDisableButtons(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                enableOrDisableButtons(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void enableOrDisableButtons(boolean isEnabled) {
        btn_three_buy_health.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        btn_ten_buy_health.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        btn_twenty_buy_health.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        btn_fifty_buy_health.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }
    @Optional
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_three_buy_health)
    void buyThreeHealth(View view) {
        buyProduct("5_buy_health");
    }
    @Optional
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_ten_buy_health)
    void buyTenHealth(View view) {
        buyProduct("10_buy_health");
    }
    @Optional
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_twenty_buy_health)
    void buyTwentyHealth(View view) {
        buyProduct("20_buy_health");
    }
    @Optional
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_fifty_buy_health)
    void buyFiftyHealth(View view) {
        buySubscription("50_buy_health");
    }

    private void buyProduct(String skuId) {
        BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSku(skuId)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams);
    }

    private void buySubscription(String skuId) {
        BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSku(skuId)
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK
                && purchases != null) {
            for (final Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                mBillingClient.consumeAsync(purchase.getPurchaseToken(), new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsumeResponse(int responseCode, String purchaseToken) {


                        if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You bought health", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
            billingCanceled();
        } else {
            billingCanceled();
        }
    }
    private void billingCanceled() {
    }
}
```

how Can I check whick item is purchased.

this toast appears in all purchases

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You bought health", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but I want it to be like this

if a person buy 10 health toast should be like this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You bought 10 health", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if a person buy 20 health toast should be like this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You bought 20 health", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Also How to check if a user has a subscription when app start?

if the user has a subscription, the toast should appear in the beginning "You are gold member"

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm still waiting, any ideas?